# Ie developer toolbar, see overridden styles?

Tags: internet-explorer-6, toolbar

Im using the Ie developer toolbar for IE6. By selecting an element I can see the CSS being applied to it. Is there a way of seeing other overridden styles the way you can with firebug?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know about the developer toolbar, but [DebugBar](http://www.debugbar.com/) will show you all CSS rules applied to the element you are looking for, even if it is overridden by another one.